# Alguien que me pueda ayudar a solucionar un problema que tengo con el boton editar estoy trabajando en JAVA con el modelo vista controlador

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, netbeans

Estoy trabajando en proyecto de JAVA con MySQL con MVC, y me ha surgido el siguiente problema. Tengo dos botones para realizar la acción `actualizar`. Primero, presiono un registro de la tabla y de ahí el botón <kbd>BUSCAR</kbd> para que el `id` del registro aparezca en el formulario.

Después de esto, lleno todos los campos que quiero editar y, al presionar el botón <kbd>EDITAR</kbd>, me aparece el mensaje `surgió un error al actualizar` y otro error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '13' for key 'PRIMARY'`.
Segun la imagen muestra que hay error en las lineas  `this.sqlConsulta.executeUpdate();`
`dbproducto.actualizar(producto);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if (e.getSource() == this.forminventario.btnBuscar) {
        int filaEditar = this.forminventario.tbProducto.getSelectedRow();
        int numfilas = this.forminventario.tbProducto.getSelectedRowCount();

        if(filaEditar>=0 && numfilas==1){
            this.forminventario.txtId.setText(String.valueOf(this.forminventario.tbProducto.getValueAt(filaEditar, 0)));

            this.forminventario.btnBuscar.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnEditar.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnEliminar.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnImprimir.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnRefrescar.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnRetirar.setEnabled(false);
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SELECCIONE UN REGISTRO");
    }

if (e.getSource() == forminventario.btnEditar) {
        try {
               int id = Integer.parseInt(this.forminventario.txtId.getText());
               String codigo = this.forminventario.txtCodigo.getText();
               String nombre = this.forminventario.txtNombre.getText();
               String descripcion = this.forminventario.txtDescripcion.getText();
               float precio = Float.parseFloat(this.forminventario.txtPrecio.getText());
               int stock = Integer.parseInt(this.forminventario.txtStock.getText());

               dbproducto.actualizar(producto);
               clean();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(forminventario, "¡REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO!");

            //this.cargarTabla("");
            this.forminventario.btnBuscar.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnEditar.setEnabled(false);
            this.forminventario.btnEliminar.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnGuardar.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnImprimir.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnRefrescar.setEnabled(true);
            this.forminventario.btnRetirar.setEnabled(true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ControladorProducto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

//Metodo actualizar
@Override
public void actualizar(Object objeto) throws Exception {
    ModeloProducto producto = (ModeloProducto) objeto;

    try {

        this.connect();

        String sql = "UPDATE productos SET idProducto = ?, nombre = ?, codigo = ?, descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ?;";

        this.sqlConsulta = this.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

        this.sqlConsulta.setInt(1, producto.getId());
        this.sqlConsulta.setString(2, producto.getNombre());
        this.sqlConsulta.setString(3, producto.getCodigo());
        this.sqlConsulta.setString(4, producto.getDescripcion());
        this.sqlConsulta.setFloat(5, producto.getPrecio());
        this.sqlConsulta.setInt(6, producto.getStock());
        //this.sqlConsulta.setInt(7, 1);

        // Executa consulta y Cerrar conexion
        this.sqlConsulta.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("SURGIO UN ERROR AL ACTUALIZAR");
    }

    this.desconectar();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error se produce porque:

1 - En tu consulta defines 5 parámetros de entrada y luego intentas dar valor a 6.

```
String sql = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = ?, codigo = ?, descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ?;";

this.sqlConsulta = this.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

this.sqlConsulta.setInt(1, producto.getId());
this.sqlConsulta.setString(2, producto.getNombre());
this.sqlConsulta.setString(3, producto.getCodigo());
this.sqlConsulta.setString(4, producto.getDescripcion());
this.sqlConsulta.setFloat(5, producto.getPrecio());
this.sqlConsulta.setInt(6, producto.getStock());
```

2 - Además el primer parámetro lo llenas como un entero pero me parece que es un `String`: `this.sqlConsulta.setInt(1, producto.getId())`.

Me parece que lo que te falta es agregar el id en tu consulta:

```
String sql = "UPDATE productos SET id = ?, nombre = ?, codigo = ?, descripcion = ?, precio = ?, stock = ?;";
```

O, dejar la consulta como está y eliminarlo cuando llenas los parámetros:

```
this.sqlConsulta.setString(1, producto.getNombre());
this.sqlConsulta.setString(2, producto.getCodigo());
this.sqlConsulta.setString(3, producto.getDescripcion());
this.sqlConsulta.setFloat(4, producto.getPrecio());
this.sqlConsulta.setInt(5, producto.getStock());
```

Comment: Hola, acabo de corregir ese error pero ahora al presionar el boton editar me aparece el siguiente error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '13' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Claro, porque ya existe el id que intentas escribir. Acabo de editar la respuesta.